# Error 500 cordova_plugins.js

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I started a basic PhoneGap project with default settings. With Firebug, i see :

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://myIP:3000/cordova_plugins.js"
```

If i go to `http://myIP:3000/cordova_plugins.js` i see:

> TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined at assertPath
>   (path.js:7:11) at Object.join (path.js:506:7) at Object.handle
>   (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap
>   Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect-phonegap\lib\middleware\cordova\cordova_plugins.js:18:33)
>   at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap
>   Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
>   at Object.handle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap
>   Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect-phonegap\lib\middleware\cordova\cordova.js:33:13)
>   at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap
>   Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
>   at resume (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap
>   Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:65:7)
>   at SendStream.error (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap
>   Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:80:37)
>   at emitOne (events.js:90:13) at SendStream.emit (events.js:182:7)

My question is: What can I do to solve error 500 ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It looks like PhoneGap Desktop is not generating the cordova_plugins.js file. I can't seem to find how to get it to do that.